# Outlook vsto - Folder restrictions

Tags: outlook, vsto, add-in

I have a little Outlook 2010 AddIn and need to restrict some actions on a custom folder:

- Can I somehow prevent the user from renaming a folder?
- Is it possible to prevent the user from moving any item to the folder? I know the ItemAdd Event, but this is only fired after the item was already moved. This is too late for me.
- Would it be possible to disable the context menu (right click) of a folder?

Thanks a lot!

// edit: I think I found a solution for the context menu problem. Is that ok or is there a flaw in doing this?

```cs
outlook.FolderContextMenuDisplay += DisableArchiveFolderContextMenu;
private void DisableArchiveFolderContextMenu(Office.CommandBar commandBar, MAPIFolder folder)
{
  if (folder.Name.Equals(Settings.Default.ArchiveFolderName))
  {
    // Disable the context menu
    commandBar.Enabled = false;
  }
  else
  {
    commandBar.Enabled = true;
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [`BeforeItemMove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mapifolderevents_12_event.beforeitemmove%28v=office.14%29.aspx) for preventing users from moving items into your folder. This event would need to be attached to every folder you are interested in watching - there is no global `BeforeItemMove` that I am aware of. You will have to recursively iterate each mailbox folder or latch onto [`Explorer.FolderSwitch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865625.aspx) and attach your item listener. The `FolderSwitch` has limitations though since you can still move items without switching folders via Inspector Ribbon, OWA, or EWS.

To keep users from renaming your folder, you can use the [`StorageItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff864182.aspx) to persist the Folder name implemented via [`FolderChange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869140.aspx) of the folders' context parent.

```cs
public partial class ThisAddIn
{
    Outlook.Folder folder;
    Outlook.Folder customFolder;
    Outlook.Folders mailbox;
    Outlook.Explorer explorer;

    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        explorer = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer();
        explorer.FolderSwitch += new Outlook.ExplorerEvents_10_FolderSwitchEventHandler(explorer_FolderSwitch);

        mailbox = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Session.DefaultStore.GetRootFolder().Folders;
        if (mailbox.Cast<Outlook.Folder>().Where(c => c.Name == "Custom Folder").Count() == 0)
        {
            customFolder = mailbox.Add("Custom Folder") as Outlook.Folder;
            Outlook.StorageItem si = customFolder.GetStorage("Custom Folder Storage", Outlook.OlStorageIdentifierType.olIdentifyBySubject);
            si.UserProperties.Add("PermanentFolderName", Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olText).Value = customFolder.Name; // store persistent name
            si.Save();
        }
        else
            customFolder = mailbox["Custom Folder"] as Outlook.Folder;

        mailbox.FolderChange += new Outlook.FoldersEvents_FolderChangeEventHandler(mailbox_FolderChange);
    }

    void explorer_FolderSwitch()
    {
        folder = explorer.CurrentFolder as Outlook.Folder; // grab new handle
        folder.BeforeItemMove += new Outlook.MAPIFolderEvents_12_BeforeItemMoveEventHandler(folder_BeforeItemMove);
    }

    void mailbox_FolderChange(Outlook.MAPIFolder Folder)
    {
        Outlook.Folder folder = Folder as Outlook.Folder;
        Outlook.StorageItem si = folder.GetStorage("Custom Folder Storage", Outlook.OlStorageIdentifierType.olIdentifyBySubject);
        if (si.Size > 0 && si.UserProperties.Count > 0 && si.UserProperties["PermanentFolderName"].Value != folder.Name)
            folder.Name = si.UserProperties["PermanentFolderName"].Value; // override users name change
    }


    void folder_BeforeItemMove(object Item, Outlook.MAPIFolder MoveTo, ref bool Cancel)
    {
        if (MoveTo.Name == "Custom Folder")
            Cancel = true; // disallow moving items here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Hooking onto the explorer folder switch did the trick for me!